# Does changing the publication dates of the posts on my recipes website penalize me on the SEO?

Tags: seo, wordpress, dates

I have a website about recipes made with Wordpress. I recently gave a new fresh look to my website by changing the theme and I also started to improve the pictures of the recipes to make them look nicer than before.

I am using the SmartMag theme, which orders the posts on my website on categories and then on chronological order. However, since I am updating the pictures of my recipes one at a time, sometimes it happens that the recipe for which I update the thumbnail picture is not shown in the homepage, because there are newer recipes that take its place in that category. I was therefore thinking to change the publication date of these updated posts, so that they would be shown on the homepage.

Is this strategy, however, going to penalize me from a SEO point of view? Note that I am only updating the pictures, so the rest of the article would remain unchanged. Therefore, I wouldn't want to create a whole new post. Moreover, since my website is about recipes and not e.g. news, in theory there should be nothing wrong about changing the publication date, or am I missing something here?

Comment: There shouldn't be any negative impact to SEO.  Part of the SEO optimizing process includes updating old content, even if it's just fresh pictures.  Additionally, Wordpress modifies the date even if you don't, especially if you have schema markup.  I.e, if you look in your head section in the raw html you'll find a <modified_time> which has the last modified date/time if you have any article schema objects.